# OpenGL Texture Mapping doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, texture-mapping

I have to texturize a mesh using the OpenGL API and shaders.

To accomplish this, I did the following steps:

1. Load the picture and create a texture

   ```
   img::ImageLoader imgLoader;
   unsigned char* data = imgLoader.LoadTextureFromFile("../Texturen/brickwork.jpg", &width, &height, true);

   glGenTextures(1, &texId);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);{
       glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
       glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
       glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
       glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
       glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   }
   ```
2. Create vertices, normals and texture coords

   ```
   std::vector<float> v, n, t;

   // actual calculation is left out to make it more readable

   obj = new GLBatch;
       obj->Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, v.size()/3, t.size()/2);{
       obj->CopyVertexData3f(v.data());
       obj->CopyNormalDataf(n.data());
       obj->CopyTexCoordData2f(t.data(), 0);
   }obj->End();
   ```
3. Load the shaders

   ```
   shaders =  gltLoadShaderPairWithAttributes("VertexShader.glsl", "FragmentShader.glsl", 2, 
       GLT_ATTRIBUTE_VERTEX, "vVertex", 
       GLT_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, "vNormal",
       GLT_ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURE0, "vTexCoord");

   gltCheckErrors(shaders);
   ```

   *(VertexShader.glsl)*

   ```
   #version 130
   in vec4 vVertex;
   in vec4 vNormal;
   in vec2 vTexCoord;

   uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
   uniform mat4 mvMatrix;
   uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
   /// Light position in Eye-Space
   uniform vec4 light_pos_vs ;
   /// Light diffuse color
   uniform vec4 light_diffuse ;
   uniform vec4 light_ambient ;
   /// Light specular color
   uniform vec4 light_specular ;
   /// Specular power (shininess)
   uniform float spec_power;

   /// Material parameters
   uniform vec4 mat_emissive;
   uniform vec4 mat_ambient; 
   uniform vec4 mat_diffuse;   
   uniform vec4 mat_specular;  

   /// output
   out vec4 color;
   out vec2 texCoords;

   void main()
   {   
       texCoords = vTexCoord;
       // Transform vertex from objekt to clip-space
       gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vVertex ;

       // Transform vertex from object to eye-space
       vec4 vertex_vs = mvMatrix * vVertex;
       vec3 ecPos = vertex_vs.xyz / vertex_vs.w;

       // Calculate light direction
       vec3 light_dir_vs = normalize(vec3(light_pos_vs.xyz));

       // Transform normals from object into eye-space
       vec3 normal_vs = normalize(normalMatrix * (vNormal).xyz) ;

       // Viewing vector in eye-space
       vec3 view_dir_vs = normalize(-ecPos );

       // Halfway vektor for Phong-Blinn light modell
       vec3 halfway_vs = normalize(view_dir_vs + light_dir_vs ) ;

       // Diffuse
       float NdotL = max(dot(normal_vs, light_dir_vs),0.0) ;
       vec4 diffuse_color = NdotL * mat_diffuse * light_diffuse ;

       // Specular
       float NdotH = max(dot(normal_vs, halfway_vs),0.0) ;
       vec4 specular_color = pow(NdotH ,spec_power) * mat_specular * light_specular ;

       // Color output
       color = mat_emissive + light_ambient*mat_ambient + diffuse_color + specular_color;
   }
   ```

   *(FragmentShader.glsl)*

   ```
   #version 130

   in vec2 texCoords;
   in vec4 color;

   uniform sampler2D textureMap;

   out vec4 fragColor;

   void main()
   {
       fragColor = texture(textureMap, texCoords);
       fragColor *= color;
   }
   ```
4. Draw everything in the display function

   ```
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   glLineWidth(INDICATOR_WIDTH);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);

   modelViewMatrix.LoadIdentity();
   modelViewMatrix.Translate(0,0,-5);
   modelViewMatrix.PushMatrix();{

       M3DMatrix44f rot;
       m3dQuatToRotationMatrix(rot,rotation);
       modelViewMatrix.MultMatrix(rot);

       // set shader
       glUseProgram(shaders);
       // pass matrices
       glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "mvpMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix());
       glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "mvMatrix"),  1, GL_FALSE, transformPipeline.GetModelViewMatrix());
       glUniformMatrix3fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "normalMatrix"),  1, GL_FALSE, transformPipeline.GetNormalMatrix(true));
       // pass light properties
       glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "light_pos_vs"),1,light_pos);
       glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "light_ambient"),1,light_ambient);
       glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "light_diffuse"),1,light_diffuse);
       glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "light_specular"),1,light_specular);
       glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "spec_power"),specular_power);
       // pass material properties
       glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "mat_emissive"),1,mat_emissive);
       glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "mat_ambient"),1,mat_ambient);
       glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "mat_diffuse"),1,mat_diffuse);
       glUniform4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "mat_specular"),1,mat_specular);

       drawObject();

   }modelViewMatrix.PopMatrix();

   gltCheckErrors(shaders);
   glutSwapBuffers();
   glutPostRedisplay();
   ```

After all those steps, the result looks fine but has no texture :(

[image: Screenshot]

What actually happens here is, that every vertex is mapped to the same pixel of my Texture which is apparently grey.

I tried texture coords from **(0,0) to (1,1)** and **(0,0) to (width,height)**
but nothing changed.

Comment: Yea sounds like your texture coordinates might not be right. Check this answer out (look at the wikipedia cube map link too): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983532/what-are-the-texture-coordinates-for-a-cube-in-opengl

Comment: Where are your `glGetUniformLocation()` and `glUniform1i()` calls for `textureMap`?

Comment: Try changing this: `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data)` to this: `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA8, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &data )` if the texture has an alpha channel or to `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, width, height, 0, GL_RGB8, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &data )` if it doesn't and also notice that I'm using the address of `data`. Also move this function call to after your `filtering & mipmap` calls. And as genpfault has mentioned you are missing calls to `glGetUniformLocation()` & `glUniform1i()`...

Comment: @FrancisCugler I'm pretty sure my color format is correct since your suggestions just make the loaded texture black. I'm not quite sure what you and @genpfault were talking about when saying `glGetUniformLocation()` and `glUniform1i()` are missing. As far as i understand, `glBindTexture()` in combination with the `sampler2D` prefix should work. Maybe thats my missconception, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @vincent I'm sorry about the screenshot, it's a bit miss leading since this is not a simple cube but a cylinder with tesselation 4.

Comment: Draw out texture coordinates as color on your mesh and make sure they are correct.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz everything maps to location (1,0). When debugging my c++ program, the coords are correct

Comment: @Rabbid76 not 100% sure but I think, this isn't the causing the error. It must be a problem with passing the tex coord to the shader. I tested various 1x1 pixel jpegs and as mentioned above, the pixel at pos (1,0) is always displayed correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
shaders =  gltLoadShaderPairWithAttributes(
    "VertexShader.glsl", 
    "FragmentShader.glsl",
    2, 
    GLT_ATTRIBUTE_VERTEX, "vVertex", 
    GLT_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, "vNormal",
    GLT_ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURE0, "vTexCoord");
```

to

```
shaders =  gltLoadShaderPairWithAttributes(
    "VertexShader.glsl", 
    "FragmentShader.glsl",
    3, // < -------------------- 
    GLT_ATTRIBUTE_VERTEX, "vVertex", 
    GLT_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, "vNormal",
    GLT_ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURE0, "vTexCoord");
```

because the 3rd parameter in the function signature is the number of the attributes that immediately follow and should be linked to the shader. In this case there are 3 attributes: `GLT_ATTRIBUTE_VERTEX`, `GLT_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` and `GLT_ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURE0`.
In the original code only `GLT_ATTRIBUTE_VERTEX`, `GLT_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` are linked an so no texture coordinates were passed to the shader.

Answer (score 1):

First, when you bind a texture you should specify the texture unit that you use for this texture.
This can be done by [glActiveTexture](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml)

```
int textureUnit = 0; // <- put the number of the txture unit in here
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 + textureUnit );
glGenTextures( 1, &texId );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId );
```

The maximum nuber of texture units can be asked by `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS,...)`.
The number of texture units is implementation dependent, but must be at least 80.
Since you only need one `0` is ok for you.
Texture unit `0` is default, so if you never change it you can skip this.

Next make sure  you used [glTexImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)
in the right way, especially check wether the format suits to your data. Use [glGetError](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml) to check if specifying the target texture succeeded.

When you use your shader program you have to link the texture unit to your uniform texture sampler.

```
int texMapLocation = glGetUniformLocation( shaders, "textureMap" );
...
glUseProgram( shaders );
...
glUniform1i( texMapLocation, textureUnit ); // <- you are missing this
```

Comment: I added the `glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "textureMap"), 0)` right after `glUseProgram(shaders)`. Also double checked the GL return code after using `glTexImage2D()`, but it still doesn't work

Comment: changed it, didn't solve it (normals are working with both vec3 and vec4 it seams)

Comment: when changing the vertex shader output to `vec4(vTexCoord.x, 0, vTexCoord.y, 1)`, the object appears red. When changing the fragment shader (`fragColor = vec4(texCoords.x, 0, texCoords.y, 1)`), the same thing happens

Comment: (1,0) I think... And yes, that's what's happening.

Comment: **Good idea!** The texture is properly loaded since i can map it that way. So at least that's working :)

Comment: Just a fiew thoughts: Am i using `gltLoadShaderPairWithAttributes` and `CopyTexCoordData2f` correctly?

Comment: The contents of vector t are correct btw... (in case i communicated that poorly)

Comment: Man I feel so stupid... OF COURSE it must be 3 x'D thanks man. Everything works now

Comment: I think it would be better if you could post it as a separate Answer, so this thread is easier to understand for others. If you do that, I'd be happy to mark it as answered ;)